# Strict inequality on the exponential function

Tags: calculus, analysis, jensen-inequality

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be real numbers such that $\beta > \alpha > 1$ and consider the exponential function $e^{-x}$. Suppose that the parameters $a$ and $b$ are in $[0,1]$ and satisfy the conditions

(1) $a+b = 1$;

(2) $b \geq \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$.

Is it possible to find $a$ and $b$ such that the inequality
\begin{equation}
a + b e^{-\beta x} \geq e^{-x}
\end{equation}
holds for $x > 0$ while satisfy the conditions (1) and (2)?

From Jensen's inequality we know that $a + b e^{-\beta x} \geq e^{-b \beta x}$. But $b \beta \geq \alpha > 1$ which makes $e^{-b \beta x} < e^{-x}$ so that it does not work here. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Perhaps, we can use Lagrange multiplier. For a start, set for $x\in R^*_+$, $f(a,b) = a+be^{-\beta x}-e^{-x}$ and write the Lagrangian function with the constraints $(1)$ and $(2)$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

Comment: Not possible. If $f(x) = 1 - b + b e^{-\beta x} - e^{-x}$, then $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1 - \beta b < 0$.